# Django template tag {{ form.my_field_xxx }}

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a django form on which i add X fields to the form on the **init** function

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    quantity = kwargs.get('quantity')
    for i in range(quantity):
        self.fields['first_field_%s' % i] = forms.CharField(label='HI Number', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))
```

in my HTML template i would like to loop here aswell

```
{% for x in form.quantity.value|get_range %}  # range filter i added
    <div>
        {{ form.first_field_x }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Where x would be a number --> form.first_field_1, form.first_field_2.

If i put the number there directly i ofcourse get the bound field.
I could also create the fields myself using direct html in the template

But is there a way to replace the X with a number so that the result would be a bound field?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that, because of the limitations of the django templating engine.

But there's a much easier solution - make "my_fields" an array, and then use an index into it, rather than the index number as part of the variable name.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    quantity = kwargs.get('quantity')
    my_fields = []
    for i in range(quantity):
        my_fields.append(forms.CharField(label='HI Number', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'})))
    self.fields['my_fields'] = my_fields
```

Then in the template:

```
{% for x in form.quantity.value|get_range %}  # range filter i added
    {{ form.my_fields[x] }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: How would this affect the ID attribute for my input? currently i have a whole range of jquery that uses this index number.

Comment: I can't tell.  You haven't provided any details about your jquery setup.